# How to control a camera with a joystick without spamming messages?

Tags: camera, remote-control

I'd like a recommandation on how to approach the problem I'm facing as a software developer.

**Context:**

I have an IP Camera that can be moved with a PTZ (Pan, Tilt, Zoom) command that can be called like so:

`PTZ(float pan, float tilt, float zoom)`

I have a joystick that update its input values every ~0.0001 sec and the available input values are:

- `joystickX`: from -1(left) to 1(right) 0 being the center
- `joystickY`: from -1(down) to 1(up) 0 being the center
- `joystickMagnitude`: from 0(untouched) to 1(completely pushed)
- `zoomButton+`: pressed(`zoomValue` = 1) or not
- `zoomButton-`: pressed(`zoomValue` = -1) or not

Right now, every time the joystick values are updated, a message to the camera is sent, so it's kinda spamming the camera every ~0.0001 sec with `PTZ` messages.

Ex:

- Joystick input value update
- `PTZ(joystickX*joystickMagnitude, joystickY*joystickMagnitude, zoomValue)` message sent
- Repeat in ~0.0001 sec

**Question:**

What would be the best approach to be able to control the camera with the joystick without spamming `PTZ` messages?

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc.

Comment: Stick something in the middle! What it will be depends on your technical skills.  For instance, a sub $5 Arduino could read the input from the joystick and only forward every 5th or 10th message, or only those with a (significant) change. Do the joystick or camera have a support forum? Try there

Comment: Aha! it's an IP camera, so maybe you can but some form of router or configure a firewall, to filter the messages without having to know programming. Good luck & let us know if you get a solution

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the intel, I wasn't sure if I was at the right place at first (:

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Thanks for the tip! I'll sure try and look into what you proposed (: